# PL/SQL trigger compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to create a trigger that will record any deletion on a table in an audit table

The trigger looks like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER cusdelete
AFTER
DELETE OR UPDATE
ON CUSTOMER
DECLARE
v_username varchar2(10);

BEGIN
SELECT V('APP_USER')
INTO v_username
FROM dual;

-- Insert record into audit table
INSERT INTO cusudit
( CUSTOMER_id,
country,
first_name,
last_name,
birth_date,
address,)
VALUES
(old.CUSTOMER_id,
old.country,
old.first_name,
old.last_name,
old.birth_date,
old.address,
sysdate,
v_username );

END;​
```

however when I try to save and compile this I get the following message:

```
*Compilation failed, line 20 (15:29:04) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. 
    This only affects the compilation of database triggers.

PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.QUANTITY'Compilation failed, line 21 (15:29:04) 
    The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. 
    This only affects the compilation of database triggers.

PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.COST_PER_ITEM'Compilation failed, line 22 (15:29:04)
    The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. 
    This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.TOTAL_COST'*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use oracle audit

```
audit delete on customer
```

and query the audit trail table

```
select * from dba_audit_trail
```

Answer (score 1):

The "*line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative*" text is just telling you to count lines starting from the `BEGIN` statement and not from the `create or replace trigger`.

The real problem is that columns `Quantity`, `Cost_Per_Item`, and `Total_Cost` don't exist in the `Customer` table. They don't look like customer-type values; are they in another table? Note that the `:old.CUSTOMER_id` reference didn't cause an error.

**Addendum**: Also, please see the comments below, where @AlexPoole points that the table being inserted into is `orders_audit`, which could mean that the trigger was meant for an `Orders` table rather than the `Customers` table.

Comment: ... although whatever is generating that message is misleading since the PL/SQL (and the error line numbering) starts at the `DECLARE`. Hadn't ever really noticed that the [syntax diagram](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#BABBJHHG) implies that everything after `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER` is part of the PL/SQL ('plsql_source'), when it's only really the `DECLARE...BEGIN...EXCEPTION...END` block that is, and I would have said everything up to that was SQL (albeit DDL). Also, `orders_audit` suggests this is being built against the wrong table too...

Comment: That mystifies me too, because I normally count from the top. I don't use SQL Developer that often and I don't even know what Apex is, so I just assumed that one of them threw this in, and that being Oracle products they were telling the truth. I originally tried a bunch of counting approaches so that `old:quantity` would show up on line 21 as reported (count from `BEGIN`, count from the top, count from the top and omit blanks, count from the top and omit blanks and comments) and none of them worked. Maybe the code grew extra lines when it was pasted into the question?

Comment: No, I think I made the same mistake initially; the quantity error is line 20. `DECLARE` is line 1. The `line 21` is referring to the next error. As well as being misleading this is trashing the formatting and making it harder than usual to follow. I don't use [Apex](http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html) (though it comes with [11gR2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/nav/portal_5.htm)) but I'd be surprised if that is doing this too.

Comment: As an aside you might want to consider moving your  "SELECT V('APP_USER')INTO v_username FROM dual;"  into a package and caching and referencing it rather than doing the select each time as that will slow it down if there are lots of rows

Comment: @Dave - I believe `v('app_user')` is an Apex thing; you can't really cache it in a trigger (as it might be different each execution), and `dual` only has one row... it's just a function call, but I'm not sure why it's being put into a local variable rather than being used directly in the `values()` clause.

Comment: INSERT INTO cusudit
( CUSTOMER_id,
country,
first_name,
last_name,
birth_date,
address,)
VALUES
(old.CUSTOMER_id,
old.country,
old.first_name,
old.last_name,
old.birth_date,
old.address,
sysdate,
v_username );